# Where and How should I add AsyncStorage with React Native 0.59?

Tags: react-native, npm

I just upgraded to `react-native 0.59.0-rc.3` and I'm getting a warning about AsyncStorage that will be removed from `react-native` and added to `@react-native-community/async-storage`.

But in the  [@react-native-community/async-storage](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-async-storage) it only says how to link it, but not how to install it
*e.g* `npm install some_package`

Where Should I install it from?
`npm install react-native-community` and just import it from that?
`npm install @react-native-community/async-storage`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it states on the [repo](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-async-storage)

```
# Install
$ yarn add @react-native-community/async-storage
```

Usually if a dependency is available with `yarn` it is available with `npm`

However, if you are using `npm` instead of `yarn` you can install it with

```
npm i @react-native-community/async-storage
```

`yarn` and `npm` are both package managers. Choose one and stick with it.

To see if a package is available for `npm` you can search on https://www.npmjs.com

As you can see from the below link that it is on `npm` and can be installed using `npm i`.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/async-storage

Answer (score 1):

The NPM package is @react-native-community/async-storage.
Have a look at the [NPM page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/async-storage) for it